# Load an edge-list into graph-tool

Tags: python-3.x, graph-tool

I want to load an edge-list into graph-tool. The vertex-indices in my list are not sequential, so I would like them to be automatically added as vertex_properties. As far as I understand this should be done with add_edge_list but I find that the vertex_property "name" is not created. On the other hand, load_graph_from_csv does work:

```
from graph_tool.all import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

```
edge_list = [[1,7,1],[7,4,5],[1,4,3]]
G = Graph(directed=False)
G.ep["length"] = G.new_edge_property("int")
eprops = [G.ep["length"]]
G.add_edge_list(edge_list, hashed=True, eprops=eprops)
print(G.vp.keys())
print(G.ep.keys())
Out: 
[]
['length']
```

So you see there are no vertex_properties in G. From the graph-tool docs for add_edge_list:

> Optionally, if hashed == True, the vertex values in the edge list are
>   not assumed to correspond to vertex indices directly. In this case
>   they will be mapped to vertex indices according to the order in which
>   they are encountered, and a vertex property map with the vertex values
>   is returned.

Now I find that load_graph_from_csv is working as I expected:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(edge_list, columns=['node_1', 'node_2', 'length'])
df.to_csv('edge_list.csv', sep=',', index=False)
G2 = load_graph_from_csv('edge_list.csv', skip_first=True, directed=False, hashed=True, eprop_names=['length'])
print(G2.vp.keys())
print(G2.ep.keys())
print([G2.vp['name'][v] for v in G2.get_vertices()])
Out: 
['name']
['length']
['1', '7', '4']
```

Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is right there in the documentation:

```
"...a vertex property map with the vertex values is returned."
```

Note it says "returned", not "added to the internal property map list".

Just do:

```
name = G.add_edge_list(edge_list, hashed=True, eprops=eprops)
```

and `name` is the property map you want.

Comment: If this solved your problem, you should accept the answer.

Comment: Also having problems with property maps as outlined here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72369634/graph-tool-edge-property-cannot-be-set-to-type-object